# How do you replace text with .replace and print the new sentence

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a mad libs program and am having trouble with `.replace` and don't know why its not working, I'm pretty new to coding and don't know too much.

```
import random

def main():
    libs = input('Hello! Would you like to play MadLibs? Enter y or n: ')
    libs = libs.lower()
    
    while libs == 'y':
        paragraph = madLibs()
        para = replace(paragraph)
        print(para)
        libs = input('Would you like to play again? ')
        libs = libs.lower()
        
    if libs == 'n':
            exit()
            
    if libs != 'y' or 'n':
        print('That is not a valid option')
        main()

def madLibs():
    madLibs = {1 : 'Today I went to the zoo. I saw a(n) ADJECTIVE jumping up and down in its tree',
               2 : "I walk through the jungle. I take out my ADJECTIVE canteen.",
               3 : 'The day I saw the Monkey King VERB was one of the most interesting days of the year.'}
    
    randNum = random.randint(1, 3)
    chosenLib = madLibs.get(randNum, 'Entry not found')
    return chosenLib

def replace(para):
    for line in para:
        if 'ADJECTIVE' in para:
            adj = str(input('Type an Adjective: '))
            para.replace('ADJECTIVE', adj)
        elif 'NOUN' in para:
            noun = str(input('Type a Noun: '))
            para.replace('NOUN', noun)
        elif 'VERB' in para:
            verb = str(input('Type a Verb: '))
            para.replace('VERB', verb)
        elif 'ADVERB' in para:
            adv = str(input('Type an Adverb: '))
            para.replace('ADVERB', adv)
        return para
        
main()
```

The problem is in the `replace` function. Why is it not replacing?

Answer (score 2):

The REPL can help elucidate what is happening:

```
>>> s = "ABC"
>>> t = s.replace("A","Alpha")
>>> s
'ABC'
>>> t
'AlphaBC'
>>>
```

Since you are just calling `replace()` and not saving the result, the original string is being returned.

That said, I think you also have a problem here:

```
def replace(para):
    for line in para:
```

It's not made clear in your code, but I think you're actually passing a single string into `replace`, which means your `for line in para` is *actually* iterating through each character in the single line you pass in. Therefore, you will never match a full word. You can (dis)prove this by printing out what is coming into the function.

Using a simplified version of what you've written, we can see this in the REPL as well:

```
>>> def madLibs():
...     return "Test ADJECTIVE string"
...
>>> def replace(para):
...     for line in para:
...         print(f"This is the line: {line}")
...
>>> paragraph = madLibs()
>>> replace(paragraph)
This is the line: T
This is the line: e
This is the line: s
This is the line: t
This is the line:
This is the line: A
This is the line: D
This is the line: J
This is the line: E
This is the line: C
This is the line: T
This is the line: I
This is the line: V
This is the line: E
This is the line:
This is the line: s
This is the line: t
This is the line: r
This is the line: i
This is the line: n
This is the line: g
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! This really helped in explaining why it was being so weird

Answer (score 0):

Your code only replaces one items then returns.  You want to keep replacing stuff until there's nothing to replace, and there's no point in doing things line by line.  Also, `input` returns a string, so there is no point in passing it to `str`.

```
def replace(para):
    while True:       
        if 'ADJECTIVE' in para:
            adj = input('Type an Adjective: ')
            para = para.replace('ADJECTIVE', adj)
            continue
            
        elif 'NOUN' in para:
            noun = input('Type a Noun: ')
            para = para.replace('NOUN', noun)
            continue

        elif 'VERB' in para:
            verb = input('Type a Verb: ')
            para = para.replace('VERB', verb)
            continue
            
        elif 'ADVERB' in para:
            adv = input('Type an Adverb: ')
            para = para.replace('ADVERB', adv)
            continue

        return para
```

There are better ways to do this by using a dict to avoid the multiple ifs.  Here's an example that builds the prompt from the part of speech being requested.

```
def replace(para):
    match = True
    while match:       
        match = False
        for part in ('ADJECTIVE','NOUN','VERB','ADVERB'):
            if part in para:
                rep = input('Type a ' + part.title() + ': ')
                para = para.replace(part, rep, 1)
                match = True

    return para
```

Note that I added "1" to the `replace` call.  That will limit it to replacing one thing at a time.  Otherwise, if you had two VERBs in the paragraph, it would replace ALL occurrences of "VERB" with whatever was typed.

Comment: Thanks for the really useful tips! This honestly helped me a lot

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have the `return` inside the loop in `replace`, so you're returning after only replacing one thing, skipping the rest.

Try bringing the `return` down an indentation level so you can go through all the lines before returning.

Comment: That's not actually the issue - he is only submitting one line and his loop is also not looping through lines, even though that's what the variable says. He's not actually replacing anything.